# Age limits for use of Trello

Tags: trello, account-management

I am looking at setting up school accounts for some of our students. Is there an age requirement for children or young people to sign up and use Trello?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the [Terms of service](https://trello.com/legal).

Since it's a free service there's no credit card/payment requirement and as far as I can see the only technical requirement is an email address.